# Update table from a list of values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of 5 values like (30, 41, 49, 28, 50) and I want to update 5 records in a table with those values. Say my table is currently:

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 26 |
| 2 | Pete | 39 |
| 3 | Dave | 45 |
| 4 | Mary | 22 |
| 5 | Jane | 42 |
| 6 | Marv | 70 |

I want to insert those new ages in the table above in the order that I've written them for ids 1 to 5, so the table becomes:

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 30 |
| 2 | Pete | 41 |
| 3 | Dave | 49 |
| 4 | Mary | 28 |
| 5 | Jane | 50 |
| 6 | Marv | 70 |

Not too sure how to go about doing that

Comment: This seems to be a very contrived requirement - might one say homework. Please provide a non-SQL based description of the issue. Also post what you have tried and the results.  How do these differ from the expected results? If you have not at least attempted a solution they describe the approach you are considering

Comment: How do you know that the value `30` belongs to id=1?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the new values into a `VALUES` clause and use that as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
   set age = t.new_age
from (
  values (1, 30), (2, 41), (3, 49), (4, 28), (5, 50)
) as t(id, new_age)
where the_table.id = t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your problem:

```
drop table if exists temp;
create table temp (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(20), age INTEGER);
insert into temp values
   (1, 'John', 26),
   (2, 'Pete', 39),
   (3, 'Dave', 45),
   (4, 'Mary', 22),
   (5, 'Jane', 42),
   (6, 'Marv',70);
  
select * from temp;
```

You have a list (30, 41, 49, 28, 50), and a table like above.

Then you can simply insert those new ages one by one:

```
update temp set age=30 where id=1;
update temp set age=41 where id=2;
update temp set age=49 where id=3;
update temp set age=28 where id=4;
update temp set age=50 where id=5;

select * from temp order by id;
```

I do not see your problem with this?

Or are you not telling all the constraints?

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a197bd228a2c06d96ae53a4127945485)

Comment: Yeah i thought of doing that but i have a lot more records to update (a list of 30 values) and want to know if there's a way to avoid writing 30 update set lines

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?  The 5 update statement above can also be written as 1 update statement, that should not make a difference to this "problem".